# How do I show that $\prod_{n=2}^\infty1-n^{-z})$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, infinite-product

What are $z$'s such that $\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-n^{-z})$ is convergent?

Let $\mathscr{R}$ be the region where the product converges.

Assume that the product is convergent at $z$. Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-n^{-z})=1$. Thus, $Re(z) >0$. Thus, $\mathscr{R}\subset \{z:Re(z)>0\}$ That's all I can do so far now.. How do I proceed?

It does not seem easy to show the convergence of $\sum Log(1-n^{-z})$.

If $Re(z)>1$, then $\prod (1+ n^{-z})$ is absolutely convergent. Hence $\{z:Re(z)>1\}\subset \mathscr{R}$. However, $\mathscr{R}$ may be strictly larger than the set $\{z:Re(z)>1\}$. Isn't it?

Comment: @AndreasT It is customary to say that the product diverges to $0$. So that is not the case.

Comment: @AndreasT, how can you say that the limit of these complex numbers will be a real number?

Comment: Right, right, after second thoughts I removed the comment :)

Comment: the terms in the sum you are mentioning are asymtotically equal to $1/n^z$ for large $n$ what does this mean for the convergence of the sum?.

Comment: @tired I don't get your comment.. Would you please be somewhat more specific?

Comment: As $n-> \infty$ , $\log(1+1/n^z)\sim 1/n^z +\mathcal{O}(1/n^{2z})$. From this u can determine conditions for the sum to converge.